# Accessing superclass method of subclass through another class in java

Tags: java, interface, subclass, superclass

What is the best solution for this problem?

This is the superClass

```
public class Views<T> {

private T controller;

public Views() {
}

public Stage getStage(Node object){
    return (Stage) object.getScene().getWindow();
}

public T getController(){
    return controller;
}

public void setController(T controller){
    this.controller = controller;
}

}
```

I have this interface:

```
public interface UserView extends Observer{
    public void setLoginObjects(Parent root);
    public void loginStartUI() throws Exception;

    public void setCriarUserObjects(Parent root, User user);
    public void criarUserStartUI(User user) throws Exception;
}
```

I have this subclass of Views:

```
public class UserViewImpl extends Views<UserController> implements UserView{
...
```

And i have this class:

```
public class UserController {

private UserView view;
private UserDAOImpl model;

public UserController(UserView view, UserDAOImpl model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;
    view.setController(this);
    this.model.addObserver(view);
}
...
```

What is the best solution for this problem?
Should i put together `Views` and `UserView`? (The problem for this solution is i will have more views, for example i have `ParqueView` and `ParqueViewImpl`, that basically will have the same methods as `Views`, so there would be repeated code and i want to avoid that)

The main problem is that inside my `UserController` i pass as parameter `UserView`, which does not have access to super class methods, and i need to access `setController` which is located in `Views` class, it doesnt make sense to change the type of `UserView` to Views in `userController` because of the MVC

Comment: "What is the best solution for this problem?" - You never explained what the problem is (the title does not suffice).

Comment: Would `ParqueView` also have/need the methods from `UserView`?

Comment: @user7 no, ParqueView needs the methods from Views

Comment: @JacobG. sorry i though the problem was pretty obvious, ill edit the post!

Comment: You could make View an interface and make `UserView` implement it?

Comment: What precisely are you seeking to achieve by using generics?

Comment: @user7 hmm, it might work because then UserView would have the method that i want to access, but i create class Views to avoid code repetition :/

Comment: @JoeC i use generics because, for UserViewImpl i will have UserController, for ParqueViewImpl i will have ParqueController

Comment: Might sound crazy - You can have one class called `ObservableView` that implemetns View and extends Observer and make `UserView` extend that. But I don't want to solve a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. We need to understand the class model to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not need generics here. Simply using an interface should suffice.

Create a `Controller` interface, which your two controllers will implement. Then you can get rid of the `<T>` entirely and use this interface instead.